# How to redirect to URL containing fragments in Facebook login?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post on Facebook Page through my app, for that, I need consent from the user and then he/she will be redirected back to a landing page which I have created.
My redirect URL is as follows:

```
https://localhost:6565/ProductName/#/SomePath/socialMediaLanding

https://www.facebook.com/v4.0/dialog/oauth?client_id="+appId+"&response_type=token&scope=publish_pages&redirect_uri="redirectURI";
```

As my redirect URL contains #, after facebook redirects me back to this page what it does is, it removes everything after # and redirect to

```
https://localhost:6565/ProductName/#access_token={access_token}
```

**As I cant remove #** from URL what I am expecting is receiving the access token at the end of the Landing Page URL like:

```
https://localhost:6565/ProductName/#/SomePath/socialMediaLanding#access_token={access_token}
```

Comment: I’m not sure if that can actually work. With the server-side login flow, properly URL-encoding the parameter should be enough to make sure your fragment is still there after the redirect back to your app - but I am not sure if that is gonna help here, because Facebook needs to manipulate the fragment itself, when you use response_type=token - and I am pretty sure they are doing that by simply overwriting any potentially existing fragment. (Plus, a URL like you want would strictly speaking not be technically valid in the first place.)

Comment: @misorude I checked the URL in redirect URL validator and it's fine, but as you said Facebook needs to manipulate the fragment, but if I made a Landing page without # then I will have to replace all the URLs in my application as they all have # as a fragment.

Comment: Would using the JS SDK and FB.login be an option? That doesn’t use redirects in the first place, so the URLs would not be a problem.

Comment: @misorude Yes!! I am thinking the same, in the meanwhile, I also tried Facebook4j but it also requires a user access token preconfigured. Thanks for taking out time:)